# Is there any way no manual bulk edit records on php MyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Is there any way no manual bulk edit records on php MyAdmin?

Thanks

Hugo

Answer (score 2):

If you want to edit multiple rows in a database, you can click the select all checkbox in the "Browse" tab, and then click the edit (pencil icon).  If you want  to edit more than the default 30 rows which show at a time, enter a higher number in the # of rows to show textbox.

**UPDATE**: If you want to UPDATE a given column in a set of selected records, there are two ways to do this.

1. If they have something in common (e.g. Column_2 has the same value), you can do an UPDATE table SET Column_1 = X WHERE Column_2 = Y
2. If there's nothing the rows you want to change have in common, then you can get the WHERE clause by selecting their checkboxes and clicking the export button (it's a table icon to the right of the delete button).  This will give you the WHERE clause.  Copy that where clause and use it in an UPDATE query.  UPDATE table set Column_1 = X WHERE [WHERECLAUSE]

Comment: Click the pencil at the bottom, not the one next to the row.  It's next to "With selected: "

Comment: I've done it. But it shows all the records selected. And I have to change it all. Is there a place where I can change ONE record and have all the selected records changed?

Comment: Are you saying you want to change one record and have all the others change to the same values?  Please update your answer to be precise what you want to change the values to

Comment: I am sorry. What I want to do is to change the value of one field of several records to a single specific value.

Comment: I didnt understand ýour answer.

Comment: What dont you understand about it?

Comment: when you 'check all' and press the pencil, it still just gives you a big list of all the checked items, which you have to go in and edit individually.  The 'check all' seems to do nothing basically