# manually select rows phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to manually select rows on which I want to run sql query? In phpmyadmin interface, there is a checkbox for every row, can that be  used for filtering rows somehow?  I can see an inline option where I can write query. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know SQL? You could use that manual query option and use a "where" clause

Comment: You mean like a `WHERE` clause? `UPDATE thetable SET column = 'new value' WHERE id IN (1,4,5,6,9)`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski that was it. I found another question with similar problem as well here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117453/is-there-any-way-no-manual-bulk-edit-records-on-php-myadmin. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can not use check box to run query on particular field.
to run query on a particular field u need to use some kind of clauses.