# Batch edit column fields of selected rows via phpMyAdmin

Tags: batch-file, phpmyadmin, edit

I have a picture gallery (built with Coppermine) and I'm trying to backdate a bunch of pictures; to do so I know that I have to edit two columns (mtime and ctime) in the coppermine DB.
Both columns are contained in a table named 'db_pictures'.
I have already done that manually and I know it works.

Now the problem is that I have to edit approx 300-400 pictures (=300-400 rows, 1 row per picture) in the 'db_pictures' table and it would take forever to do that manually.

I thought this could be done quicky and effortlessy with the right command so I searched the site and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6117603/4127275); unfortunately I get a syntax error when I try to apply this command:

UPDATE `db_pictures` SET `ctime`=[new value] WHERE [old value]

What am I doing wrong? Could somebody tell me how to apply the right command, please?

Comment: Not much more to say above my current answer not knowing `ctime`/`mtime` data type ([SHOW COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html)) **and** `[old value]`/`[new value]` expressions. Please have in mind that *syntax error* is **too broad** description as there might be dozen reasons. Please [edit] your question and be more specific observing [mcve] rules.

Answer (score 0):

Condition in `WHERE` clause must evaluate to a **boolean** value i.e. ´true´ or `false`, see [UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE db_pictures SET ctime=[new value] WHERE ctime=[old value]
```

or, as your question seems to be a bit unclear,

```
UPDATE db_pictures SET ctime=[new value] WHERE mtime=[old value]
```

Comment: "Condition in WHERE clause must evaluate to a boolean value i.e. ´true´ or false, see UPDATE Syntax"

Oh, I understand...
Is there another command that could help me with my problem?

Comment: I don't know if this will clarify my question but both ctime and mtime values express dates, in two different ways;

mtime has to be set with this format: YYYY-MM-DD (ex. 2016-06-19) while ctime is a timestamp that has to be converted with a Unix Timestamp Converter -> http://www.4webhelp.net/us/timestamp.php (ex. 1466363303)